# How to add page to the end of another page for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation, frame

I want to create a analog of shell's tabbar (shell doesn't appropriate for me) with 2 buttons at the end of every page. I created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="IndDict.NavigationButtons">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            <Button Text="Dictionary" Pressed="DictOpen"/>
            <Button Text="Tools" Pressed="ToolsOpen"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Any ideas how to add this to the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="IndDict.Page3">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

? Thanks for responding!

Comment: You can't embed a page in a page.  You can use a ContentView containing the buttons and include that at the bottom of every page

Comment: Yes, good idea to use ContentView! Completly foregot about this component! Thank you for advice!

Comment: You can try to embed a contentview or a custom control/layout instead of the page.